# Getting autoincrement values with Slick library in Scala

Tags: scala, slick

How do I get the auto-incremented values for records inserted with Slick? The following code prints 1111. I would have expected it to print 1234

```
import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._

object TestMappedTable extends App{
    case class User(id: Option[Int], first: String, last: String)

    object Users extends Table[User]("users") {
        def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
        def first = column[String]("first")
        def last = column[String]("last")
        def * = id.? ~ first ~ last <> (User, User.unapply _)
    }

  implicit val session = Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1", driver = "org.h2.Driver").createSession()
  session.withTransaction{
    Users.ddl.create

    print(Users.insert(User(None, "Jack", "Green" )))
    print(Users.insert(User(None, "Joe", "Blue" )))
    print(Users.insert(User(None, "John", "Purple" )))
    print(Users.insert(User(None, "Jim", "Yellow" )))
  }
}
```

I'm using Slick 0.11.2 for Scala 2.10.0-RC1

Comment: Does the database show 1, 2, 3, 4?

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra Yes, the id's are auto-incremented correctly.

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure the return value of Insert is the id? I can't find insert in the ScalaDoc documentation. Got a link?

Comment: I kinda assumed it was, but turns out I was wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Data manipulation queries usually return the number of rows affected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can retrieve the generated value like this.

Add `autoInc` method to `Users` object.

> def autoInc = id.? ~ first ~ last <> (User, User.unapply _) returning id

Use `Users.autoInc.insert` instead.

> print(Users.autoInc.insert(User(None, "Jack", "Green" )))

See also:

https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/10

https://github.com/slick/slick/commit/09a65a8e88a0363412e218dc5c06023b69809649

Comment: This worked great for the H2 database, but PostgreSQL does not like it. Since this is not quite the same problem, I asked it as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13199198/828757

Comment: What can be done when tables are larger? maybe 15-20 columns... the `forInsert` method becomes a monster!

Comment: This is now supported by Slick. See [Brenden's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27314304/1772454) below. Same is also possible in [Slick 3.0](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html#inserting).

Answer (score 9):

The latest version of Slick (2.1.0) automatically takes care of [ignoring the auto-incremented ids](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/queries.html#inserting) and the documentation demonstrates how to retrieve the id:

```
val userWithId =
  (users returning users.map(_.id)
         into ((user,id) => user.copy(id=Some(id)))
  ) += User(None, "Stefan", "Zeiger")
```

This is the full monty, where the retrieved value is then inserted back into the object you are adding to the table. If you just want to get your hands on the id itself:

```
val userId =
  (users returning users.map(_.id)) += User(None, "Stefan", "Zeiger")
```

Both code snippets were taken from the official docs. It seemed like this question needed updating for newcomers (like me) who have never used earlier versions of Slick.

Comment: This is more up to date answer. I am not sure if you can 'edit' the currently selected answer to add this as an update or at least link to this.

Comment: But why is userId of type `FixedSqlAction[Int, NoStream, Effect.Write]`? (tested in Slick 3.0.0) How to get the Int / Long?

Answer (score 0):

According to [SLICK Inserting document](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/lifted-embedding.html#inserting), you should define a method `forInsert` looks like:

```
def forInsert = first ~ last <> (
    { t =>
        User(None, t._1, t._2)},
    { (u: User) =>
        Some((u.first, u.last))
    }) returning id
```

To get result:

```
def save(user: User): User = {
    val id = users.forInsert.insert(user)
    new User(Some(id), user.first, user.last)
}
```

Comment: could that last line be `user.copy(id = Some(id))`?

Answer (score 0):

For me, following source worked (Slick 3.0.2)

```
class Track(tag: Tag)
   extends Table[(Int, String, String)](tag, "TRACK") {
   // This is the primary key column:
   def id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
   def artist: Rep[String] = column[String]("ARTIST")
   def name: Rep[String] = column[String]("NAME")

   def * : ProvenShape[(Int, String, String)] =
     (id, artist, name)
}
```