# Using Auto Incrementing fields with PostgreSQL and Slick

Tags: scala, slick, typesafe-stack

How does one insert records into PostgreSQL using AutoInc keys with Slick mapped tables? If I use and Option for the id in my case class and set it to None, then PostgreSQL will complain on insert that the field cannot be null. This works for H2, but not for PostgreSQL:

```
//import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._
//import scala.slick.driver.BasicProfile.SimpleQL.Table
import scala.slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple._
import Database.threadLocalSession

object TestMappedTable extends App{

    case class User(id: Option[Int], first: String, last: String)

    object Users extends Table[User]("users") {
        def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
        def first = column[String]("first")
        def last = column[String]("last")
        def * = id.? ~ first ~ last <> (User, User.unapply _)
        def ins1 = first ~ last returning id
        val findByID = createFinderBy(_.id)
        def autoInc = id.? ~ first ~ last <> (User, User.unapply _) returning id
    }

 // implicit val session = Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1", driver = "org.h2.Driver").createSession()
    implicit val session = Database.forURL("jdbc:postgresql:test:slicktest",
                           driver="org.postgresql.Driver",
                           user="postgres",
                           password="xxx")

  session.withTransaction{
    Users.ddl.create

    // insert data
    print(Users.insert(User(None, "Jack", "Green" )))
    print(Users.insert(User(None, "Joe", "Blue" )))
    print(Users.insert(User(None, "John", "Purple" )))
    val u = Users.insert(User(None, "Jim", "Yellow" ))
  //  println(u.id.get)
    print(Users.autoInc.insert(User(None, "Johnathan", "Seagul" )))
  }
  session.withTransaction{
    val queryUsers = for {
    user <- Users
  } yield (user.id, user.first)
  println(queryUsers.list)

  Users.where(_.id between(1, 2)).foreach(println)
  println("ID 3 -> " + Users.findByID.first(3))
  }
}
```

Using the above with H2 succeeds, but if I comment it out and change to PostgreSQL, then I get:

```
[error] (run-main) org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
```

Comment: this example might be of use to someone: https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/2.0.0-RC1/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/examples/lifted/MultiDBCakeExample.scala

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is working here:

```
object Application extends Table[(Long, String)]("application") {   
    def idlApplication = column[Long]("idlapplication", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def appName = column[String]("appname")
    def * = idlApplication ~ appName
    def autoInc = appName returning idlApplication
}

var id = Application.autoInc.insert("App1")
```

This is how my SQL looks:

```
CREATE TABLE application
(idlapplication BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
appName VARCHAR(500));
```

**Update:**

The specific problem with regard to a mapped table with User (as in the question) can be solved as follows:

```
  def forInsert = first ~ last <>
    ({ (f, l) => User(None, f, l) }, { u:User => Some((u.first, u.last)) })
```

This is from the [test cases in the Slick git repository](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/797e81172cd152ed7fce8cd2e3335a8dac8edb9b/slick-testkit/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/slick/testkit/tests/MapperTest.scala#L20).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a scala beginner, I think I misunderstood your example. I'm using the driver version 9.1-901-1.jdbc4.

I've edited my answer to illustrate exactly what I'm doing here. Hope it helps.

Comment: @JacobusR have you solved the issue with id being null when sending it as in your question, with `None`? Because I have that issue too...

Comment: @JacobusR Thanks a lot! My question is also, if for instance your `last` would be an int value as `Option[Int]` how you'd define it? Another `forInsert` for this specific case? Because if I define it like `Option[Int]` I have to put None each time I add an insert, while there be cases when this is not None...

Comment: Hi Christian, I'm not sure I understand... Won't you please ask it as a separate question so that you can post a larger part of your code. With a bit of luck, some other clever Slick guru stumbles over your question and sets us both straight :-)

Comment: Just a note.  If your data type is int or bigint and you want to use AutoInc, you need to create a sequence and set the default to use the sequence.

Comment: What can be done when tables are larger? maybe 15-20 columns... the `forInsert` method becomes a monster!

Comment: Have to agree with @alexBrand, this solution is pretty stupid when you have tables with a large amount of columns, the amount of boilerplate is ridiculous.

Slick should automatically handle the ```Option[Long]``` and ```id.?``` case automatically when dealing with postgres

Comment: Did anyone attempt to make this work with Slick 2.0.1? The default projection syntax has changed so the above code doesn't compile and I can't find any working example with Postgres

Answer (score 11):

I tackled this problem in an different way. Since I expect my `User` objects to always have an id in my application logic and the only point where one would not have it is during the insertion to the database, I use an auxiliary `NewUser` case class which doesn't have an id.

```
case class User(id: Int, first: String, last: String)
case class NewUser(first: String, last: String)

object Users extends Table[User]("users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def first = column[String]("first")
  def last = column[String]("last")

  def * = id ~ first ~ last <> (User, User.unapply _)
  def autoInc = first ~ last <> (NewUser, NewUser.unapply _) returning id
}

val id = Users.autoInc.insert(NewUser("John", "Doe"))
```

Again, `User` maps 1:1 to the database entry/row while `NewUser` could be replaced by a tuple if you wanted to avoid having the extra case class, since it is only used as a data container for the `insert` invocation.

**EDIT:**
If you want more safety (with somewhat increased verbosity) you can make use of a trait for the case classes like so:

```
trait UserT {
  def first: String
  def last: String
}
case class User(id: Int, first: String, last: String) extends UserT
case class NewUser(first: String, last: String) extends UserT
// ... the rest remains intact
```

In this case you would apply your model changes to the trait first (including any mixins you might need), and optionally add default values to the `NewUser`.

*Author's opinion: I still prefer the no-trait solution as it is more compact and changes to the model are a matter of copy-pasting the `User` params and then removing the `id` (auto-inc primary key), both in case class declaration and in table projections.*

Comment: +1 Thanks for sharing. The duplication of the members is not ideal (one may consider traits or inheritance), but it does make the code very readable.

Answer (score 2):

We're using a slightly different approach. Instead of creating a further projection, we request the next id for a table, copy it into the case class and use the default projection '*' for inserting the table entry.

For postgres it looks like this:

Let your Table-Objects implement this trait

```
trait TableWithId { this: Table[_] =>
  /**
   * can be overriden if the plural of tablename is irregular
   **/
  val idColName: String = s"${tableName.dropRight(1)}_id"
  def id = column[Int](s"${idColName}", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def getNextId = (Q[Int] + s"""select nextval('"${tableName}_${idColName}_seq"')""").first
  }
```

All your entity case classes need a method like this (should also be defined in a trait):

```
case class Entity (...) {
  def withId(newId: Id): Entity = this.copy(id = Some(newId)
}
```

New entities can now be inserted this way:

```
object Entities extends Table[Entity]("entities") with TableWithId {
  override val idColName: String = "entity_id"
  ...
  def save(entity: Entity) = this insert entity.withId(getNextId) 
}
```

The code is still not DRY, because you need to define the withId method for each table. Furthermore you have to request the next id before you insert an entity which might lead to performance impacts, but shouldn't be notable unless you insert thousands of entries at a time.

The main advantage is that there is no need for a second projection what makes the code less error prone, in particular for tables having many columns.

Comment: Interesting approach, but ties the application directly to Postgres. A database independent approach would be to use Slick's `Sequence` class and have each driver implement according to sequence naming convention (e.g. Postgres' is "tableName_pkName_seq"). Batch inserts won't work so well with nextval unfortunately. Not sure if current Slick (3.0) solves the boilerplate issue referenced in accepted answer comments; if not, pretty hideous having to manually map out case class as a tuple sans pk column...

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution was to use the SERIAL type like this:

`def id = column[Long]("id", SqlType("SERIAL"),  O.PrimaryKey,  O.AutoInc)`

Here's a more concrete block:

```
// A case class to be used as table map
case class CaseTable( id: Long = 0L, dataType: String, strBlob: String)

// Class for our Table
class MyTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[CaseTable](tag, "mytable") {
  // Define the columns
  def dataType = column[String]("datatype")
  def strBlob = column[String]("strblob")

  // Auto Increment the id primary key column
  def id = column[Long]("id", SqlType("SERIAL"),  O.PrimaryKey,  O.AutoInc)

  // the * projection (e.g. select * ...) auto-transforms the tupled column values
  def * = (id, dataType, strBlob) <> (CaseTable.tupled, CaseTable.unapply _)

}


// Insert and  get auto incremented primary key
def insertData(dataType: String, strBlob: String, id: Long = 0L): Long = {
  // DB Connection
  val db = Database.forURL(jdbcUrl, pgUser, pgPassword, driver = driverClass)
  // Variable to run queries on our table
  val myTable = TableQuery[MyTable]

  val insert = try {
    // Form the query
    val query = myTable returning myTable.map(_.id) += CaseTable(id, dataType, strBlob)
    // Execute it and wait for result
    val autoId = Await.result(db.run(query), maxWaitMins)
    // Return ID
    autoId
  }
  catch {
    case e: Exception => {
      logger.error("Error in inserting using Slick: ", e.getMessage)
      e.printStackTrace()
      -1L
    }
  }
  insert
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem trying to make the computer-database sample from play-slick-3.0 when I changed the db to Postgres. What solved the problem was to change the id column (primary key) type to SERIAL in the evolution file /conf/evolutions/default/1.sql (originally was in BIGINT). Take a look at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#%21topic/scalaquery/OEOF8HNzn2U
for the whole discussion.
Cheers,
ReneX

Answer (score 1):

Another trick is making the id of the case class a var

```
case class Entity(var id: Long)
```

To insert an instance, create it like below
`Entity(null.asInstanceOf[Long])`

I've tested that it works.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've found is to use `SqlType("Serial")` in the column definition. I haven't tested it extensively yet, but it seems to work so far.

So instead of

```
def id: Rep[PK[SomeTable]] = column[PK[SomeTable]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
```

You should do:

```
def id: Rep[PK[SomeTable]] = column[PK[SomeTable]]("id", SqlType("SERIAL"), O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
```

Where `PK` is defined like the example in the "Essential Slick" book:

```
final case class PK[A](value: Long = 0L) extends AnyVal with MappedTo[Long]
```