# Get auto increment key in scalaquery

Tags: scala, jdbc, scalaquery

I want to insert rows in 2 tables which represent a 1:n relationship using scalaquery / slick.

The tables are defined as follows:

```
object CompanyBaseTable extends Table[CompanyBaseTableEntry]("company") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O PrimaryKey, O AutoInc)
}

object ProductCatalogueTable extends Table[ProductCatalogueEntry]("product_catalogue") {
 def cid = column[Int]("id", O NotNull)
 def pid = column[Long]("pid", O NotNull)
 def company = foreignKey("company_fk", cid, CompanyBaseTable)(_.id)
}
```

I want to insert the 1:n relation within one transaction but I don't know how I can achieve that using ScalaQuery. In JDBC 3 you can get the generated ID from the [statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853066/sql-java-get-value-assigned-to-auto-increment-primary-key), but I don't see where the statement is exposed in the ScalaQuery API, neither do I see a way to access this information directly.

Comment: did you check if the company object you are saving have the id field populated?

Comment: It is a case class thus immutable therefore I doubt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scala-query is now SLICK. There was an [issue](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/10) raised on github but it seems to have been fixed. This is the [commit](https://github.com/slick/slick/commit/09a65a8e88a0363412e218dc5c06023b69809649) if you want to have a look at it.

This answer also tells you how to get the id
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13114949/152601